# Subset of Generic Abstract List - C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, abstract-class

I am making some abstract base classes. The base object is defined as:

```
    public abstract class Bar
    {
        public bool Enabled;
    }
```

The base collection is defined as:

```
 public abstract class Foo<T> : List<T>
        where T : Bar
    {
        public Foo<T> GetAllEnabled()
        {
            Foo<T> ret = new Foo<T>();

            foreach (T item in this)
            {
                if (item.Enabled)
                {
                    ret.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Naturally, I get an error trying do create a `new Foo<T>()`, because Foo is an abstract class. Without the abstract modifier, everything works fine, but I want the modifier there because I want to make sure the class gets derived.

I have tried

```
     Type U = this.GetType();
        Foo ret = new U();
```

but I get an error "The type or namespace name 'U' could not be found (blah blah blah)".

I think my attempted fix should work, and I must just have the syntax wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: Take a look at `Type.GetConstructor` or `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: Thanks Eric and Anthony, that is what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Type U = this.GetType();
Foo ret = new U();
```

`Type U` will contain information on the data type, it is not the equivalent of a generic type parameter that you can then instantiate. You can use `U` to create a type through `Activator.CreateInstance`, which has a few overloads and accepts `Type` objects, but then you're left with needing to cast the resulting object to an appropriate type in order to be able to *use* it.

```
Type type = this.GetType();
Foo<T> ret = (Foo<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: @Grasshopper @Anthony Would Activator.CreateInstance be able to create an instance of an abstract class? The MSDN documentaiton at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx says that you will get a MemberAccessException if you attempt to create an instance of an abstract class using CreateInstance(Type). Or maybe I am just reading this incorectly.

Comment: @Waleed, it's not creating an instance of the abstract class, it's creating an instance the same type of `this` and casting that *to* the abstract class, which is all perfectly legal. `this` will be `DerivedFoo<T>` (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

```
but I want the modifier there because I want to make sure the class gets derived.
```

As per your own words, you will need to derive a class that you can then instantiate.

Comment: I want to write this functionality once, not in 6 derived classes, and I dont want to clutter up my code with a derived "Foo2" class - there is no need for 2 base classes for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is an error to instantiate the abstract class `Foo<T>`. That is a direct consequence of being abstract.

> but I want the [abstract] modifier there because I want to make sure the class gets derived.

Then derive it first, `class Foo2<T> : Foo<T> { }` and then instantiate `Foo2<T>`.

Comment: I want to write this functionality once, not in 6 derived classes, and I dont want to clutter up my code with a derived "Foo2" class - there is no need for 2 base classes for the same thing.

Comment: @Grassh: ??? We're not seeing the whole picture but I would suggest a rethink about what you are doing  here. If this is for testing it might be OK, but any way of (or need of) instantiating an abstract class in production code looks like a severe design error.

Answer (score 0):

And what type do you want to create? What are you actualy trying to acomplish? Why are you forcing to derive from your collection class? You dont need collection to be abstract, if you want its items to be abstract. Especialy with generics.

Also : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/27/585476.aspx (I think there is much better article, but I cant find it)

Comment: I want to create an instance of the derived type that the method is called from. I want the collection to be abstract to force the downstream devs to derive from this class instead of directly instantiating it.